# how to show long float number in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have dataset values in long float

```
var dataSet = [
  {
    "c1": 3.690000057220459,
    "date": "1970-01-07 09:30:00",
    "c2": 3.690000057220459,
  },
  {
    "c1": 3.6700000762939453,
    "date": "1970-01-07 09:30:01",
    "c2": 3.6700000762939453,
  },
  {
    "c1": 3.690000057220459,
    "date": "1970-01-07 09:30:02",
    "c2": 3.690000057220459,
  }
]
```

When I am show this data in D3.js, I am unable to see any difference.

[image]

Also, trying to publish this data in line graph without using any other library

Code for above image is:-

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="canvas"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var dataSet = [
  {
    "c1": 3.690000057220459,
    "c2": 3.690000057220459,
  },
  {
    "c1": 3.6700000762939453,
    "c2": 3.6700000762939453,
  },
  {
    "c1": 3.690000057220459,
    "c2": 3.690000057220459,
  }
]

let dataSet2 = dataSet.map( d => d.c1)
var svgWidth = 500;
var svgHeight = 500;
var barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = (svgWidth/dataSet.length);


 const canvas = d3.select(".canvas")
 const svg = canvas.append("svg")
.attr('width', svgWidth)
.attr('height', svgHeight);

var barChart = svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(dataSet2)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d){
    return svgHeight - d;
  })
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return d
  })
.attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
.attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    var translate = [barWidth*i, 0];
    return "translate ("+translate+")";
  })
.attr("fill", 'blue')

 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please suggest

Comment: The values differ by 0.5% or less - they should look very similar. Also, if you are using the values as a pixel value, how can you nudge the top of a bar up by hundredths of a pixel? You could use a scale, set the domain to something like 3.6 and 3.7, with a range of a few hundred pixels, that'll enable seeing a difference: `d3.scale.linear().domain([3.6,3.7]).range([0,500])` - d3.scaleLinear in d3v4/5, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7qsvz850/)

Comment: @AndrewReid Thanks for your help. I got your point and your suggestion is working fine for these three records. However, facing one more issue related to bigger data.

I have multiple records (https://jsonblob.com/c949d71c-92a5-11ea-9d3b-3b069e62c0bf) and when I am using 

```scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([3.6,3.8]).range([0,500]);```

its giving me error on console i.e., ```"Error: <rect> attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-0.00023841857932360743")" ```

Please suggest

Comment: Looks like you hava a value just under 3.6, which would return a value that is negative. Try expanding the domain a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AndrewReid I tried domain range([0.2,9.9]) but still there is an issue. Can we do something else?